# best practice for single page loaded by ajax and seo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web, seo

I'm developing a site wich has the following structure:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <sub-section>
            Content 1
        </sub-section>
        <sub-section>
            Content 2
        </sub-section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <sub-section>
            Content 3
        </sub-section>
        <sub-section>
            Content 4
        </sub-section>
    </section>
</body>
```

Once the page is loaded all the sections are loaded by ajax. The site has two language so if the user decides to switch the language, all sections are loaded again but in a different languaje.

The goal is to get each section indexed as a different page by the google crawlers.

My approach so far is the following:

Each section has metadata: keywords, title, etc. When a user types: mysite.com/section_name the page is loaded with the metadatada of the required section.

The problem is that when googles crawls it will see that each different pages has different metadata values but the same html structure.

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a few links that might help you with the subject of creating HTML snapshots.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992 
[HTML Snapshot for crawler - Understanding how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890075/html-snapshot-for-crawler-understanding-how-it-works)